# .prefs file pattern in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-preferences, filepattern

I am very very new to Android Studio and coding in general. I'm working on a project that involves me moving open sourced code to android studio emulator. However, one of the folders that needs to be moved over is the .settings folder. It contains a file called "org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs". When I tried to add it as a file, android studio does not have a file pattern that recognizes .prefs. How else would I be able to add this file in? Thank you!

Comment: no you won't be able to add it.....but opening that project you can have access to all the files in it

Comment: What file pattern would work though? There is only the one .prefs file in the .settings folder

Comment: i don't have knowledge of eclipse but studio builds the project with gradle files.